# Concatenate derived currency symbol and value in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, concatenation

I am using MSSQL (2012) and need to return a numeric value that is cast in decimal to include the relevant currency symbol. I have returned the currency symbol using `CASE` as follows:

```
SELECT (CASE (Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' END) AS Currency_Symbol
```

I would then like to concatenate this with the numeric value, which I have had to `CAST` to correct the decimal places as follows:

```
SELECT CAST(Price AS decimal(10,2)) AS Unit_Price
```

However, I seem unable to use `CONCAT` or any other method to do this, and as I understand it I won't be able to reference the 'Currency_Symbol' value in the same `SELECT` statement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does something like this work? SELECT CASE (Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' END + cast(CAST(Price AS decimal(10,2)) as varchar(10)) AS Unit_Price

Comment: I'm wondering if you already have a currency table, with ids 1 and 2, descriptions 'uk' and 'usa', if you can extend that table with another column, symbol, and then do a full outer join limiting by currency ID to look up the symbol.  Don't know if you can change the table, though.

Comment: @Sean Lange +1 This works and is exactly what I was looking for in the end

Comment: @Beth I would normally do something like this, however I can't make any changes to these particular tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
declare @Currency_ID int, @dec decimal(8,2)
set @Currency_ID = 1;
set @dec = 123.45
SELECT (CASE (@Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' END) + cast(@dec as varchar)
```

Modified .. If you are using a table and the `Currency_ID` and `Unit_Price` is from a table

```
SELECT (CASE (Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' END) + cast(Unit_Price as varchar) FROM SOMETABLE
```

Comment: This seems to work with the static value of 123.45 - how would I alter that to reflect the actual value of Unit_Price? Ive tried changing the third line to `set @dec = TableName.Unit_Price`, however receive the error that 'The multi-part identifier "...Unit_Price" could not be bound'. Thanks.

Comment: It will be something like this `SELECT (CASE (Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' END) + cast(Unit_Price as varchar)` where in the select statement Currentcy_ID and Unit_Pirce will be a table column. Modified the answer to include example of using a table.

Comment: Thanks, both of these work and for ease of use in my situation (and SQL knowledge!) I've used the example using a table as `SELECT CASE (Currency_ID) WHEN (1) THEN '£' WHEN (2) THEN '$' WHEN (3) THEN '€' END + CAST(CAST(Unit_Price AS decimal(10, 2)) AS varchar(10)) AS [Unit Price]`